# RxJS: Updating a `combineLatest` with more/less Observables to combine

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactivex

I'm trying to do something like the following:

```
const streams = [];
streams.push(rxjs.fromEvent(uiItem1, 'input'));
streams.push(rxjs.fromEvent(uiItem2, 'input'));
streams.push(rxjs.fromEvent(uiItem3, 'input'));
const combinedStream = rxjs.combineLatest(...streams);

// In a galaxy far, far away...
combinedStream.subscribe((bunchAValues) => {
  const minValue = Math.min(bunchAValues);
  // do cool stuff with minValue.
});

// Later, back on Earth:
streams.push(rxjs.fromEvent(uiItem4, 'input'));
delete streams[2];
// how to update combinedStream?
```

At the end of that, I would like to do the equivalent of `combinedStream = rxjs.combineLatest(...streams);`, but in-place. Of course I could do that out-of-place (is that a term?), but then I would need to unsubscribe from the old Observable and subscribe to the new one. I could have some extra structure in place that notifies the subscriber in the far away galaxy to update its subscription to the new Observable, but the subscriber lives in an entirely different part of the program, and by separation of concerns shouldn't have to care how inputs are added and removed from `combinedStream`.

I'm aware that the idea of modifying objects in-place goes against the philosophy of functionalism, which I guess RxJS tries to follow when possible. At the same time, what I'm asking for above seems to me like a very natural thing to do: The subscriber in Andromeda just wants a stream of arrays to take the minimum of, it doesn't care where they originate from or how many streams were combined.

What's the simplest, most elegant and robust way of achieving what I want?

EDIT: In retrospect my question could have been worded more clearly. I've added my own answer below, which mostly solves the problem, but not without pitfalls. Hopefully it clarifies what I'm trying to achieve. Better solutions are welcome.

Comment: I think you should simplify you thoughts...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `takeUntil` and `skipUntil` operators:

```js
import { fromEvent, combineLatest } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil, skipUntil, first } from 'rxjs/operators'

const whenThisEmitsEverythingChanges$ = fromEvent(myButton, 'click')
    .pipe(first()); // say that you event is a click button.

const input1$ = fromEvent(uiInput1, 'input');
const input2$ = fromEvent(uiInput2, 'input')
    .pipe(takeUntil(whenThisEmitsEverythingChanges$));
const input3$ = fromEvent(uiInput3, 'input');
const input4$ = fromEvent(uiInput4, 'input')
    .pipe(skipUntil(whenThisEmitsEverythingChanges$));

const combinedStream = combineLatest([input1$, input2$, input3$, input4$]);

// In a galaxy far, far away...
combinedStream.subscribe((bunchAValues) => {
  const minValue = Math.min(bunchAValues);
  // do cool stuff with minValue.
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and sorry for taking so long to get back tot his. I see I was somewhat unclear with my question: Although your solution works for the example case I gave, what I'm really looking for is something that allows me to keep adding and removing inputs of `combinedStream` to my heart's content, whereas your solution seems specific to the case of adding one input and removing another and calling it day. I've added my own answer which hopefully clarifies what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I came up with:

```
class VariableSourceSubject extends rxjs.Subject {
  constructor(joinFunction) {
    super();
    this.joinFunction = joinFunction;
    this.sources = new Set();
  }

  addSource(source) {
    this.sources.add(source);
    this.renewInnerSubscription();
  }

  removeSource(source) {
    this.sources.delete(source);
    this.renewInnerSubscription();
  }

  hasSource(source) {
    return this.sources.has(source);
  }

  renewInnerSubscription() {
    const innerObservable = this.joinFunction(...this.sources);
    if (this.innerSubscription) {
      this.innerSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
    this.innerSubscription = innerObservable.subscribe(this);
  }
}
```

With that, I can do stuff like

```
const stream1 = streams.push(rxjs.fromEvent(uiItem1, 'input'));
const stream2 = streams.push(rxjs.fromEvent(uiItem2, 'input'));
const combinedStream = new VariableSourceSubject(rxjs.combineLatest);
combinedStream.addSource(stream1);
combinedStream.addSource(stream2);

// In a galaxy far, far away...
combinedStream.subscribe((bunchAValues) => {
  const minValue = Math.min(bunchAValues);
  // do cool stuff with minValue.
});

// Later, back on Earth:
const stream3 = rxjs.fromEvent(uiItem4, 'input'));
combinedStream.addSource(stream3);
combinedStream.removeSource(stream2);
// The subscription to combinedStream is now receiving the latest
// values from stream1 and stream3.
```

This seems to be sufficient for my use case, but doesn't really fully implement what I was originally asking for. Specifically, since I'm combining the various sources with `combineLatest`, and a new `innerObservable` is created every time a source is added or removed, all the remaining sources have to emit at least once after each removal/addition before `combinedStream` emits anything. Better solutions are welcome.